# How can I create a confusion matrix (and if possible an ROC curve) through Keras?

Tags: python, keras, metrics, image-segmentation, confusion-matrix

I am trying to implement 3D brain tumor segmentation through this Kaggle project: https://www.kaggle.com/code/rastislav/3d-mri-brain-tumor-segmentation-u-net.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics = ['accuracy',tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=4), dice_coef, precision, sensitivity, specificity, dice_coef_necrotic, dice_coef_edema, dice_coef_enhancing, testfunc] )

# Evaluate the model on the test data using evaluate
print("Evaluate on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_generator, batch_size=100, callbacks= callbacks)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)
```

In the metrics argument of model.compile, I have searched for a function/class to pass in that will generate a confusion matrix, but I have not found it. I tried using sci-kit learn Confusion Matrix but that only accepted NumPy arrays, while it was getting Tensors. I also tried returning True positives, negatives, and such seperately, but I got the error: TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable. I then tried to create my own function as each function in the metrics list is passed in y_true and y_pred, but they are in a Tensor format and it is not letting me convert them into NumPy arrays. Can anyone help me with making a confusion matrix from the test data?

Comment: Please note that the confusion matrix is not a scalar metric. You may want to try pertinent metrics such as precision, recall, f-score, AUC, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot confusion matrix with Keras data generator using sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303001/plot-confusion-matrix-with-keras-data-generator-using-sklearn)

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution, but my DataGenerator does not have classes property. I am wondering what model.predict_generator is actually returning when I pass in my test generator. Since there are 45 test files, and it is returning a numpy array of shape (100, 128, 128, 4) and values 0 through 1, I'm not sure if it is averaging the probabilities of all of them, and how I can make a confusion matrix from this.

Comment: It looks like this is a 4-class segmentation class, so the last dimension `, 4)` is probably representing the class for each pixel. You'll need to extract this and compare to the ground truth to build the confusion matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by using flatten() on both my arrays and then putting it through sklearn confusion matrix because it cannot use 3D or more numpy arrays. I could also get the ROC curve through this method.

Comment: You should add the code to make your answer useful